# PHPUnit, testing a method that uses class fields set according to current time

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm building a little Timer class that has a `start()` and `stop()` method, each of these will set a **Carbon** object with the current timestamp, then i have the method i'm trying to test, this method will calculate the difference between timestamps to get the total number of seconds elapsed in the Timer.

I'm having a problem unit testing this method, because it depends on the current timestamp, i don't think putting a `sleep(1)` in the test is a good idea, so, my question is, is there any way i can make the method use two other specific Carbon instances while it's running?

This is my method as it stands, it uses the two **protected** fields `endTime` and `startTime` from it's class.

```
/**
 * Get the total elapsed time as the difference in seconds
 * between startTime and endTime
 *
 * @return int Number of seconds elapsed
 */
public function getElapsedTime()
{
    if(!$this->endTime)
        return $this->startTime->diffInSeconds(Carbon::now('Europe/Lisbon'));

    return $this->startTime->diffInSeconds($this->endTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using Reflection

```
/**
 * The elapsedTime method should return a string
 * if both startTime and endTime are defined
 */
public function testElapsedTimeMethod()
{
    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($this->timer);
    $startTime  = $reflection->getProperty('startTime');
    $endTime    = $reflection->getProperty('endTime');

    $startTime->setAccessible(true);
    $endTime->setAccessible(true);

    $startTime->setValue($this->timer, Carbon::createFromTimestamp(1483240345));
    $endTime->setValue($this->timer, Carbon::createFromTimestamp(1483240348));

    $secondsElapsed = $this->timer->getElapsedTime();

    $this->assertEquals(3, $secondsElapsed);
}
```